# How to make elements inside a div stay in the same place when resizing the window?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, division

I'm trying to put a button over an image that will show some data , I did that part but when I resize the browser window or go to mobile view the buttons don't stay on the same spot . So basically what I need to do is to make  the buttons follow the image when resizing the window. I will put my code here and the picture of the website and hopefully someone can help me .

P.S I tried to include the google buttons and image I used in the code bellow but I'm not sure how, I'm sorry but I think that wont be the problem. Peace

```css
.mlin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  padding-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#mlincontainer {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: inherit;
  align-items: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#cols9 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border: 0;
}

.tempbuttons {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#temp1,
#temp2 {
  display: flex;
  border: 0;
}

#temp1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -260px;
  left: 80px;
}

#temp2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -260px;
  left: 280px;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <h3 id="headline"> MLIN </h3>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 25px;">

    <div id="mlincontainer" style="margin-top: 25px;">
      <img class="mlin" src="images/mlin-small.png">

    </div>
    <!--buttons -->
    <div id="cols9" class="col s9">
      <div class="tempbuttons">
        <a id="temp1" class="btn disabled">25c</a>
        <a id="temp2" class="btn disabled">33c</a>
        <div class="col s3">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    
    
    <!--I used google materialize for my buttons thats why they can't load -->
```

Comment: Please add your code in fiddle and share it here, the code you shared here isn't showing anything

Comment: I found what I was looking for here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4x9GyqBWE0